# Targeting iframe in image map anchor opening own page

Tags: firefox, iframe, target, imagemap

Here's what I got... for some reason when I click the image map links they open up the page outside the iframe (as in it opens up as it's own page)

I've messed with it for a couple hours and went through about 20 pages but none of them specifically deal with image map links and none of them are helping.

The live link is here, I'm using firefox.

http://www.penumbra-productions.com

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Penumbra Productions</title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#dropshadow").hide();

            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#dropshadow").fadeIn(1000)
            }, 1500);
        });
    </script>

    <link href="CSS/Penprocss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: #CCC;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="dropshadow">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <a href="Index.html">
                <img src="Images/PenproFull.jpg"
                     width="309" height="199"
                     alt="Penumbra Productions"
                     longdesc="http://penumbra-productions.com/Index.html"/>
            </a>
            <br/>
        </div>
        <div id="navigation">
            <img src="Images/Navigation.jpg" width="1200" height="50" border="0" usemap="#Map"/>
            <map name="Map" id="Map">
                <area shape="photography" coords="29,5,252,43" href="photo.html" target="content"/>
                <area shape="videography" coords="319,6,516,43" href="video.html" target="content"/>
                <area shape="portfolio" coords="572,9,761,44" href="port.html" target="content"/>
                <area shape="contact" coords="801,9,981,42" href="contact.html" target="content"/>
                <area shape="about" coords="1020,9,1185,43" href="about.html" target="content"/>
            </map>
        </div>

        <iframe id="content" src="main.html" width="1200" height="620" frameborder="0"></iframe>

        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok... all that needed to happen was to add the name="content" attribute to the iframe so the image map links could target it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the target attribute of the area tag, try using an onclick handler.

```
...
<area shape="contact" coords="801,9,981,42" href="#" onclick="loadNow('contact.html')" />
<area shape="about" coords="1020,9,1185,43"  href="#" onclick="loadNow('about.html')  />
...
function loadNow(url) { document.getElementById('content').src=url; }
```

Comment: i see the logic... but why the hell is it not working like it should to begin with o.O?

Comment: ok... all that needed to happen was to add the name="content" attribute to the iframe so the image map links could target it